# Replace part of matched string with Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose I have string like this ".1.12.3.4.12.4."

As a result I would like to get  ".01.12.03.04.12.04."

As you can see, I want all numbers of length == 1 to become of length == 2 with zero at the beginning. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var input = ".1.12.3.4.12.4.";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\.(\d)(?=\.)", ".0$1");
Console.WriteLine(output); // .01.12.03.04.12.04.
```

Comment: this won't match `1.2.4` i.e 1 at the beginning

Comment: @Anirudh OP didn't say that it needed to.

Comment: thax dude. this is the winner. but all approaches mentioned above also work great. but yours is the shortest :)

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into tokens, format each resulting number and then join them back:

```
var input = ".1.12.3.4.12.4.";
var output = string.Join(
    ".", 
    input.Split('.')
         .Select(i => i.Length == 0 ? "" : i.PadLeft(2, '0'))
);
```

The best part of this solution is that you can easily change the length of the padded result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
Regex.Replace(input,@"(?<=^|[.])(?=\d([.]|$))","0");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = string.Join(".", str.Split(".").Select(n => n.Length == 1 ? "0" + n : n));
```